# Dimple Js repeats ticks when there are only a few values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

When I only have one or two data points, dimple js will repeat the same ticks. How do I make it not do that?

Example

[image: Image of the below code. 1/1/1990 repeats multiple times]

```
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "Word":"1/2/1990", "Awesomeness":2000 },
      { "Word":"1/1/1990", "Awesomeness":3000 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addTimeAxis("x", "Word");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    chart.draw();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Heading home for the weekend. I'll check back on this on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'll set [axis.ticks](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#ticks) but when using a time axis you'll want to set [timePeriod](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#timePeriod) and [timeInterval](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#timeInterval). This will set one tick mark per day in the data set.

```
var xAxis = chart.addTimeAxis("x", "Word");
xAxis.timePeriod = d3.time.days;
xAxis.timeInterval = 1;
xAxis.tickFormat = "%A";
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

[image]